# ImportError: cannot import name 'HandDetection' from 'handDetection'

Tags: python

how do I solve this problem ??

I need help from friends who are professionals in solve with problems in Python

I have to do

1. reinstall python and select pip
2. my pip library was complete
3. change the python interpreter
4. install the handDetection in CMD

and that still not working

Comment: How did you install handDetection?  As far as I know, that's not a standard module.  Where did it come from?

Comment: pip install handDetection, its type in CMD not terminal sir

Comment: there is a package called `handDetection` (which btw doesn't look maintained or documented) on PyPi, but it does not seem to have any import called `HandDetection`. Perhaps a description of what you are trying to achieve and where you found instructions to install this might help.

Comment: It looks like, for the one you got, you need `from handDetection.hand_tracking_module import handDetector`.  It needs OpenCV and mediapipe.